# A Swift input method switcher works only after changing focus to another window

Tags: swift, macos, input, keyboard-shortcuts

I am trying to write a MacOS app which switch input methods by previously assigned shortcut(`command+space` in here).
Switching input methods preoperly works so that the language icon at the status bar(top right) immediately changes as I put the shortcut.
The problem I got in here is that the actual input method does not change.
For example, if I run my app when the selected input method is Korean, then although the status bar is showing the selected input method is Japanese after `command+space`, what I can only type is Korean characters.
However, after I change focus to another text app(e.g. from sublime text to xcode), only then the selected input method is reflected well.
I am using MacOS Monterey 12.6 and Xcode 13.1.

My project contains two source files.
The code in the file `AppDelegate.swift` is as follows:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    var switcher = Switcher()
}
```

And the code in the file `Switcher.swift` is as follows:

```
import Cocoa
import MASShortcut

class Switcher{
    var lang: Int = 0
    
    var kr: TISInputSource?
    var jp: TISInputSource?
    var en: TISInputSource?
    
    init(){
        let inputSourceNSArray = TISCreateInputSourceList(nil, false).takeRetainedValue() as NSArray
        let inputSourceList = inputSourceNSArray as! [TISInputSource]
        for inputSource in inputSourceList {
            if inputSource.id == "com.apple.inputmethod.Korean.2SetKorean" {
                self.kr = inputSource
            }
            if inputSource.id == "com.apple.inputmethod.Kotoeri.RomajiTyping.Japanese" {
                self.jp = inputSource
            }
            if inputSource.id == "com.apple.keylayout.ABC" {
                self.en = inputSource
            }
        }
        self.register()
    }
    
    func switchLang(){
        self.lang = (self.lang + 1) % 3
        switch lang {
        case 0:
            TISSelectInputSource(self.kr)
        case 1:
            TISSelectInputSource(self.jp)
        case 2:
            TISSelectInputSource(self.en)
        default:
            print("error")
        }
    }
    
    func register() {
        let langShortcut = MASShortcut(keyCode: kVK_Space, modifierFlags: [.command])
        MASShortcutMonitor.shared()?.register(langShortcut, withAction: {
            self.switchLang()
        })
    }
}
```

I wrote these codes by referring KAWA, but KAWA does not make this issue.
I have analyzed all codes of KAWA several times, I couldn't find out why the same problem does not occur in KAWA.
I am quite new to Swift, and I have no idea to approach.
Could you help me....? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered this problem before, and the reason was that the sandbox was enabled.

Comment: If you have more information please add to your answer. Otherwise consider replying in the comments section instead of posting the answer.